# Ubuntu 16 can't boot, Screen keeps flickering

Tags: nvidia

I have Windows 10 / Ubuntu 16 dual boot. Which looks something like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=XF_brXu2Lp4&app=desktop

I tried

1. Disabling the secured UEFI boot
2. Tried to purge Nvidia drivers but got this

   ```
   E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
   E: Unable to lock the administrator directory, are you root?
   ```

I'm locked out since 4 days now. I'm a begineer, please help me out

Comment: dit you try boot repair with the lieve cd?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know how to do that

Comment: How exactly did you try to `purge` Nvidia drivers? How did you try it in general if you're title says `Ubuntu 16 can't boot` ..?

Comment: Advanced Boot - Recovery mode
Then, clicked on root and tried to purge

Comment: Google: "download boot repair" - donwload the live boot cd, burm hin on a CD,  and boot with this cd.  Follow the instructions.

Comment: will i lose my data?